# Sorting Table 2 columns Month And Year

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, sql-order-by, ms-access-2007

I have a table name MyTable and have 3 columns ID, Months, Years.

```
ID ¦ Months  ¦Years       
----------------------        
1  ¦ December¦ 2019        
2  ¦ January ¦ 2019        
3  ¦ February¦ 2020        
4  ¦ January ¦ 2020
```

I used Query

```
"Select * from MyTable ORDER BY Years"
```

OutPut:

```
ID ¦ Months  ¦Years
----------------------
1  ¦ December¦ 2019
2  ¦ January ¦ 2019
3  ¦ February¦ 2020
4  ¦ January ¦ 2020
```

Then i tried Query

```
"Select * from MyTable ORDER BY  Months, Years"
```

Output:

```
ID ¦ Months  ¦Years        
----------------------        
1  ¦ December¦ 2019
3  ¦ February¦ 2020
2  ¦ January ¦ 2019
4  ¦ January ¦ 2020
```

But i want output like

```
ID ¦ Months  ¦Years
----------------------
2  ¦ January ¦ 2019
1  ¦ December¦ 2019
4  ¦ January ¦ 2020
3  ¦ Febuary ¦ 2020
```

I am new to this forum and programming i am sorry if this question is repeated. I have search for my question but i didnt find the exact solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Select * from MyTable ORDER BY Years, Months
```

When you say `ORDER BY A, B`, ordering by `B` will only be done for situations where `A` is the same. See the "ORDER BY Several Columns Example" in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp.

But as @GMB notes in the other answer, you're probably better off converting to a date and ordering by that. Otherwise for any given year the months will be ordered alphabetically, rather than based on the actual calendar sequence.

Comment: Thanks For quick reply. I solved my problem  by putting months in numeric values like jan as 1  feb as 2 etc and boom... It solved my problem

Comment: I edited my table's column Months values to 01 to 12 as months. Then i tried your query and boom it worked for me. Thank u very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt fails because you are storing months as names, so you can't use that for sorting.

You could concatenate the values from both columns in a format like `'December 1, 2019'`, and then use [function `DateValue()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to convert it to a `date` datatype, that you can use for sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY DateValue(Months & ' 1, ' & Years)
```

Comment: Thanks For quick reply. I solved my problem by putting months in numeric values like jan as 01 feb as 02 etc and used Order by years, months. And boom... It solved my problem –